# SQL Query to Count data between 6:00 Am to next day 6:00 AM

Tags: sql, oracle, delphi-7

I am new to programming.

I want to count the column value from 6 Am to next day 6 AM. I tried using the below query but it gives the value for 12 AM to 12 AM. The Query is

```
SELECT      (COUNT  (COLUMN_NAME)) AS TOTAL
FROM        TABLE_NAME
WHERE       AREA = 1
AND         TRIM(DATE_COLUMN) = TRIM ((SYSDATE)+6/24)
```

Here I cannot use date, this will update the value in Windowsforms app developed in delphi2007.

Comment: `trim()` is for string/character values , **not** for `DATE` columns. you probably meant to use `trunc()`

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(column_name) as total
from the_table
where area = 1
  and the_date_column 
           between trunc(sysdate) + interval '6' hour 
               and trunc(sysdate + 1) + interval '6' hour;
```

`trunc(sysdate)` sets the time part of the date to 00:00:00 when you then add 6 hours to that you get 06:00 (6 AM)

`trunc(sysdate + 1)` returns a date a midnight so if it's currently `2016-10-08 17:00:00` that will return `2016-10-09`. If you add 6 hours to that, it's 06:00 the next day.

---

Not sure what you mean with "I can not use DATE". If made the big mistake to store your dates as  `VARCHAR` you should change that and store them correctly in a `DATE` column. If for one reason you can't do that, you should convert that column to a date and compare dates, not strings:

```
and to_date(the_date_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') between ...
```

Make sure you specify the correct format mask to convert the `varchar` to a `DATE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2014-01-01';     
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '2014-01-02';       

SET @BeginDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 9, @StartDate);  
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 8, @EndDate);     

SELECT
 YourTable.ReadingDate,
 YourTable.Hours,
 YourTable.Data1,
 YourTable.Data2,
 YourTable.Data3
FROM
 YourTable
WHERE
 DATEADD(HOUR, YourTable.Hours, YourTable.ReadingDate) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: That is not valid for oracle

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't use  date? 
you may use a charcter string and change format to properly one.

```
variable = '2016-10-08'
to_Date(varable||' 06:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
```

If you want just get values between today 6 o'clock and ensuing day 6 oclock 
For example

```
SELECT (COUNT (COLUMN_NAME)) AS TOTAL 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE AREA = 1 
AND DATE_COLUMN between trunc(sysdate,'DD') + 6/24 and trunc(sysdate+1,'DD') + 6/24
```